# .apply() vs spread operator in node

Tags: node.js, logging, apply, console.log

All I'm trying to do is prepend my console.log with a custom message. If it can be done in an easier way that I'm attempting it, please let me know.

I have an ES6 module `logger` with a method `log`

```js
const { Console } = require('console');

const console = new Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);

module.exports = {
  date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).split('T')[0],
  time: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).split('T')[1],
  log() {
    process.stdout.write(`[${this.date} ${this.time}] INFO `);
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
};
```

Now when I run `logger.log()` I get an output of:

```js
logger.log('--- Some text 1 ---');
[2021-03-22 16:42:46] INFO --- Some text 1 ---
logger.log('--- Some text 2 ---', { aa: 11 });
[2021-03-22 16:42:46] INFO --- Some text 2 --- { aa: 11 }
logger.log('--- Some text 3 ---', 'another string');
[2021-03-22 16:42:46] INFO --- Some text 3 --- another string
```

which is exactly what I want!
**BUT** ESLint is complaining `Use the spread operator instead of '.apply()'.` [ESLint reference here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-spread) and I want to have a clean code so I comply changing my code to:

```js
const { Console } = require('console');

const console = new Console(process.stdout, process.stderr);

module.exports = {
  date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).split('T')[0],
  time: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).split('T')[1],
  log(...args) { // CHANGE HERE
    process.stdout.write(`[${this.date} ${this.time}] INFO `);
    console.log(args); // CHANGE HERE
  }
};
```

now ESLint is happy, but running the same tests yields different results:

```js
logger.log('--- Some text 1 ---');
[2021-03-22 16:40:57] INFO [ '--- Some text 1 ---' ]
logger.log('--- Some text 2 ---', { aa: 11 });
[2021-03-22 16:40:57] INFO [ '--- Some text 2 ---', { aa: 11 } ]
logger.log('--- Some text 3 ---', 'another string');
[2021-03-22 16:40:57] INFO [ '--- Some text 3 ---', 'another string' ]
```

Why the spread operator version is suddenly outputting an **array** of my arguments?
I can't do `console.log(args.join(' '))` as the second test will come out as `--- Some text 2 --- [object Object]`
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter is telling you to use spread syntax instead. But you aren't using spread syntax in the `console.log` call. (You're using *argument rest* syntax to collect all arguments into an array called `args`, but you still need to call `console.log` with those array items as separate arguments)

```
log(...args) {
    process.stdout.write(`[${this.date} ${this.time}] INFO `);
    console.log(args);
}
```

should be

```
log(...args) {
    process.stdout.write(`[${this.date} ${this.time}] INFO `);
    console.log(...args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing. I see I need to properly understand spread syntax.